# argument juggling impossible because arguments.length also increases when undefined is passed

Tags: javascript

I have a scale function which has the following signature**s**:

```
scale (xy, cx = 0, cy = 0)
scale (x, y, cx = 0, cy = 0)
```

My function definition looks like this:

```
function scale (x, y = x, cx = 0, cy = 0)
```

To make sure that the case `scale (xy, cx = 0, cy = 0)` works I need to do arguments juggling. I used to do it that way:

```
if (arguments.length == 3) {
  // juggle
}
```

However, when this function is used from another function which only relays its parameters it gets problematic:

```
function scaleFoo(x, y, cx, cy) {
    return scale (x, y, cx, cy)
}
```

`scaleFoo` doesnt care if its parameters are valid. It just relays everything.
But in that case `arguments.length` is ALWAYS 4. Even if `cy` is `undefined`.

I am aware that I can use `scale.call` to solve this but I need to pass a `this` in that case which I really would like to avoid. I would prefer a solution which uses a better `if` branch.

Comment: you could use either default values and two functions or no default values and a check for the forth argument.

Comment: Can't you replace `arguments.length == 3` with `cy === undefined`? If you call scale with 3 arguments, cy will be undefined, and if you call it with fourth argument set to undefined cy will be... undefined too

Comment: no because when you only pass one parameter, cy is undefined and you juggle even if you dont want (because y = y and cx becomes y aka x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function scaleFoo(x, y, cx, cy) {
    return scale (x, y, cx, cy)
}
```

When you pass the arguments by name you get in a wrapper function like this you will pass `undefined` if one of the wrapper is called with three parameters. For example, `scaleFoo(1, 2, 3)` will cause it to then call `scale(1, 2, 3, undefined)`.

You could add logic to check the parameters in the wrapper function as well but does not scale (no pun intended) well. Imagine the original function then needs to handle up to five parameters. You will need to include the parameter counting logic in the wrapper again.

Another way you could go is checking if each parameter is `undefined` or not but that's also not feasible a lot of times, for example if that's indeed a valid value.

Instead, you can simply use [Function#apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to pass the entire arguments object from the wrapper to the original function:

```js
function scale (x, y = x, cx = 0, cy = 0) {
  console.log("Number of arguments passed: ", arguments.length);
  console.log("x", x, "y", y, "cx",  cx, "cy", cy);
}

function scaleFoo(x, y, cx, cy) {
    return scale.apply(this, arguments);
}

scaleFoo(1);
scaleFoo(1, 2);
scaleFoo(1, 2, 3);
scaleFoo(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

There is no other real good way to wrap the function and still act on different number of passed in values without forwarding the `arguments` in some fashion, either through `Function#apply` or its ES6 replacement [the spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: As stated in my question I am aware about call. So I also now about apply. I asked for another solution. However I feel like there is non

Comment: i would work with spread as well `return scale(...arguments);`, but you omit default values.

Comment: Yes - I just figured the same. `scale(...arguments)` is the way to go. `scaleFoo` does not have default values so that is fine (additionally this would have been the case with apply too). Feel free to make that an anwer!

Comment: @Fuzzyma well, I don't think you have much of an alternative. Spreading is syntactic sugar on `.apply`. I'll add it to my answer to be more explicit but I don't there really is anything else you can do - you either re-implement the argument checking logic in the wrapper or go through each argument and see if it's `undefined` or not. Both don't scale well.

Comment: I forgot to add, if you don't want to pass `this`, then you can simply omit it by calling `.apply(null, arguments)`. If the function doesn't use `this`, then it wouldn't matter. If it does, then presumably you are already doing something to have the correct context, either through using `scale = scale.bind(correctContext)` or arrow functions or otherwise making `this` a non-factor, in which case, it doesn't matter what value of `this` you pass in.

Comment: @vlaz For me its more than sugar. You dont need to handle the `this` binding of apply which can be really ugly (ugly example: `a.b.c.d.scale.apply(a.b.c.d, x, y...)`. This just goes away when you simply call `scale(...arguments)`

Comment: That's what syntactic sugar is. It's a shorter way to do the same operation. `a.b.c.d.scale.apply(a.b.c.d, arguments)` and `a.b.c.d.scale(...arguments)` are equivalent, differing only in the syntax. So for you, the spread syntax is *exactly* sugar.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to tell you some ways

```
function scaleFoo(x, y, cx, cy) {
  // Here arguments.length will be 3. and cy will be `undefined`
  // Therefore whenever you will call scale function it will four arguments
    return scale (x, y, cx, cy)
}
```

You can do something like this

```
function scaleFoo(x, y, cx, cy) {
    if (arguments.length === 3)
        return scale (x, y, cx)
    else
        return scale (x, y, cx, cy)
}
```

However it would be always better if you pass `undefined` from your code like

```
scale(x, void 0, cx, cy)
// void 0 == undefined
```

And inside your scale function condition should be like

```
function scale(x, y, cx, cy) {
    if (y === void 0) {}
}
```

Comment: yes it would be better codedesign to not allow 3 parameter input. However that is nothing I decide but the user. For the first approach: Yes that could work but would make a lot of extra logic... guess I have to use call after all...